# How do I return a pointer to something in the middle of a char array?

Tags: c++, string, pointers

How do I return a pointer to something in the middle of a char array?

```
// Returns a pointer to the first occurrence of the given character in the
// given string.
const char* strchr(const char* string, char charToFind) {
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++) {
        if (string[i] == charToFind) {
            return string[i]; // <== THIS IS WRONG, How do I fix this?
        }
    }
    return '\0';
}
```

Comment: the failure path should be returning `null` not `\0` - technically you are returning the character value 0 and doing an implicit cast to `char*`

Comment: @oliver: What is `null`? You mean `NULL` or `nullptr`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
return &string[i];
```

or like this:

```
return string+i;
```

It's the same thing.

Returning `'\0'`, a `char` constant equal to zero, is logically incorrect: you should return `0` for a `NULL` pointer, or if you wish to return an empty C string, you could return a pointer to local *static* empty string, like this:

```
const char* strchr(const char* string, char charToFind) {
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++) {
        ...
    }
    // Not found - return an empty string:
    static const char *empty = "";
    return empty;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a pointer to a string, adding N to it will return the pointer to the part of the same string, starting from the Nth character (for zero-based count).

Also, it's better to have a constant for the pointer to empty string.

```
static const char* EMPTY_STRING = '\0';

const char* strchr(const char* string, char charToFind) {
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++) {
        if (string[i] == charToFind) {
            return string+i; 
        }
    }
    return EMPTY_STRING;
}
```

Comment: `EMPTY_STRING` is rather a misleading name for a null pointer. Or did you mean to initialise it with `""` rather than zero?

Answer (score 0):

As @dasblinkenlight mentioned, `&string[i]` or `string + i` both work for returning pointers to the middle of the string.  And as @Oliver Matthews stated, you should be returning NULL if the character is not found.  Perhaps beyond the scope of your original query, but for performance reasons, you may want to avoid calling `strlen()`, and just check for the end of string as you scan, like so:

```
const char* strchr(const char* string, char charToFind) {
    for (int i = 0; string[i]; i++) {    // Or you could say string[i] != '\0'
        if (string[i] == charToFind) {
            return string + i; 
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```